# https://1:443 のIPアドレスは何を表すのでしょうか

Tags: network

Webサーバーのアクセスログを見ていて下記のようなログがありました。

```
https://1:443
```

その他のログでは「×××.×××.×××.×××」のような見たことのあるIPv4のアドレス形式でした。
上記の場合だと、「1」の部分がIPアドレスに該当すると思うのですが、そのような形式のIPアドレスがあるのでしょうか？
IPv6なのかもと思ったのですが、その場合だと「::1」になるのかなと考えております。

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[IPアドレス](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP%E3%82%A2%E3%83%89%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B9#%E8%A1%A8%E8%A8%98)に

> - ドットがないときは、単一の32ビット数と解釈される。ロングIPアドレスなどとも呼ばれる。
>
>   - （例）3232235521 (= 192.168.0.1、192 × 2563 + 168 × 2562 + 0 × 256 + 1 = 3232235521)

と説明があるように、 `1` は `0.0.0.1` を指します。